# How can a view use a model that uses generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, refactoring

In MVC 3, I've been refactoring my controllers to remove some duplicate code by using generics which I was successful in doing, but now I'm trying to refactor my views, but I can't seem to adjust the model that the view uses to use generics.

Here is the relevant portion of my refactored abstract base controller:

```
public abstract class CrudController<TEntity> : Controller where TEntity : Entity, INamedEntity, IOrderedEntity, IHasMembers, new()
{
  private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
  protected readonly IRepository<TEntity> Repository;

  protected CrudController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
  {
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    Repository = _unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<TEntity>();
  }

  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
    return PartialView(Repository.FindById(id));
  }

  // More actions here...
}
```

Here are my actual controllers (they are really basic since the refactoring):

```
public class StatusController : CrudController<MemberStatus>
{
  public StatusController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
  {
  }
}

public class PositionController : CrudController<MemberPosition>
{
  public PositionController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
  {
  }
}
```

Note that both **MemberStatus** and **MemberPosition** implement 'Entity, INamedEntity, IOrderedEntity, IHasMembers'

Now here are my **Edit** views for those two controllers which I want to refactor:

```
@model MyApp.Domain.Entities.MemberStatus
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EntityForm" }))
{
  @Html.Hidden("Id")
  <label class="Name">
    <span>New Name:</span><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
  </label>
}

@model MyApp.Domain.Entities.MemberPositions
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EntityForm" }))
{
  @Html.Hidden("Id")
  <label class="Name">
    <span>New Name:</span><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
  </label>
}
```

You can see that the views are almost identical, with the exception of the first line which declares the model.  I want to find out how to pass in a generic parameter like I did with the controllers, which I thought (in my naivete) would look something like the following, but this obviously doesn't work.

```
@model <TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, INamedEntity, IOrderedEntity, IHasMembers, new()
```

How can I refactor these two views (by putting a generic view in the Shared folder) that would implement a non-concrete model in the view?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

FYI - I *think* (though I haven't tried) that I could use a ViewModel, but I would prefer not to have to do that in this case (as I would have to implement the mapping from the entities to the ViewModel for each entity which somewhat defets the purpose of this refactoring).

Comment: Why not have an abstract/base class that all TEntity inhert from and use that?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# MVC3 - Refactoring - " and such. That's what tags are for, and your title is much more readable without that stuff in front of it.

Comment: Just a tip, instead of looking up the controller name out of the Route Data you can pass null and it will internally pull the controller name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both of your models have common properties, create an interface with those properties in the interface, then make both models implement that interface. Now create a view that's strongly-typed to that interface. Another option is simply just a weakly-typed view that is dynamically evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I think I'm going to go for an abstract class, but should be the same principle.  I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Could you just have the model defined as whichever interface you're using rather than an object which implements many interfaces?:

```
@model INamedEntity
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EntityForm" }))
{
 @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

For this you can create an editor template for the INamedEntity interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
@model Entity
@if (Model is INamedEntity)
{
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("NamedEntityFields", (INamedEntity)Model); }
}
@if (Model is IOrderedEntity)
{
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("OrderedEntityFields", (IOrderedEntity)Model); }
}
```

NamedEntityFields.cshtml:

```
@model INamedEntity
@* put name specific fields here *@
```